# OpenCV C++ listing files in a directory?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am developing a C++ project with OpenCV. I was thinking to use Boost library to do a simple ls, but I  would like to follow opencv standars..

How can I do a cross plataform listing files with opencv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV is not created to solve such problems - you have to use another API. Look at [this stacloverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c). It seems that it's cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

There is a header

opencv2\contrib\contrib.hpp

It contains a class called Directory and few functions like GetListFiles,

GetListFolders and GetListFilesR.

You can try it out, but it's not available in Opencv3.